# onAuthenticationSuccess redirectresponse to login

Tags: symfony

Its on symfony 2.8, i'm trying to use an API and even though i'm entering the onAuthenticationSuccess method after filling the rights parameters, the redirection always goes to the login page and so, doesnt do the job.

I think its a security issue or a route issue but my knowledge is limited.

here is the function i'm entering before being redirected:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @throws InvalidParameterException
 * @throws MissingMandatoryParametersException
 * @throws RouteNotFoundException
 * @throws ServiceCircularReferenceException
 * @throws ServiceNotFoundException
 * @throws InitializeDataStudioException
 * @throws DBALException
 * @throws ORMInvalidArgumentException
 * @throws OptimisticLockException
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 * @throws \Exception
 */

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        return null;
    }

    $route = $request->get('_route');
    $request->query->remove('boid');
    $request->query->remove('uid');
    $request->query->remove('securityString');
    $request->query->remove('sessid');
    $parameters = array_merge($request->query->all(), $request->attributes->all());
    $url = $this->router->generate($route, $parameters);

    /** @var DatabaseManager $dbManager */
    $dbManager = $this->container->get('app.database.manager');

    if ($dbManager->getListUniqueKey() !== null) {
        /** @var ExistingDataLoader $dataLoader */
        $dataLoader = $this->container->get('app.database.loader.existing_data');
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');
        /** @var CustomTable $listTable */
        $listTable = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:CustomTable')->findOneBy(['type' => Table::TYPE_LIST]);

        $dataLoader->load($listTable);
    }

    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

I'm being redirected to another route then to the login page.

security.yml :

## To get started with security, check out the documentation:

## http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

security:

```
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    ds_provider:
        id: app.security.dynamic_user_provider

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - app.security.token_authenticator
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/data-studio, roles: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

the routes i'm trying to access :

data-studio/api/calculated-fields/2/edit?dailyUpdate=1&dailyUpdateTime=01:00&boid=xxx&uid=xxx&securityString=xxxxxxxxx&sessid=xxxxxxxxx

redirecting to :

/data-studio/api/calculated-fields/2/edit?dailyUpdate=1&dailyUpdateTime=01%3A00&_route=api_calculated_field_edit&_route_params%5Bid%5D=2

then :

/login

---

When entering onAuthenticationSuccess i dump the token and i can see that i'm correctly authenticated with the role "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN" :

```
  ["roles":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role)#375 (1) {
      ["role":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role":private]=>
      string(16) "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
    }
  }
  ["authenticated":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Can you show your security.yml and the url where you redirect?

Comment: OFC i continue the post with it.

Comment: Do you sure than token is populated with the correct user and user has ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN? Can you dump it?

Comment: Well, i'ts a put request so i'm able to dump it but maybe not as effienciency as i should. On my securityController my gettoken->getUser() is .anon but in my AppBundle/security/TokenAuthenticator.php my user is succesfully created with role super admin.

Comment: i just can't find the paths used by the application since its a put method. Do you know any way to debug that kind of request ?

Comment: Returned by TokenAuthenticator::getUser($credential, $userProvider) :

object(AppBundle\Entity\User)#415 (13) {
  ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
  int(1)
..............
["roles":"AppBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"

Returned by SecurityController::loginAction($request) :
.anon

i feel like it should not pass by loginAction... but it does

Comment: Best way to debug it is a PhpStorm + XDebug

Answer (score 0):

*Its the PUT method that cause this problem.
Once i switch the route to GET, it works fine.
Don't know why, help will still be appreciated.*

[ EDIT ]

Had to return null in onAuthenticationSuccess function to make it work.

Not sure if it's the correct way to do but it solves my problem and doesnt seem to have any security impact.